# tkinter freezes when "destroyed" from an open python session

Tags: python, tkinter

**PROBLEM**: tkinter's `root.destroy()` function freezes because of the last line in my program, `code.interact(local=locals())`

**BACKGROUND**: I am running my program from the terminal. It generates some text data, creates an instance of a class with said data, and drops me off in a python session where I can then run methods and test everything. This interpreter session is made possible with `code.interact(local=locals())`

From here, I run an "edit" method that allows the user to edit the generated text in a tkinter text box, and then push a button to save and quit. The button calls a function that saves a new txt file and then uses `root.destroy()` to end the tkinter mainloop. However, this freezes and does not actually close the window. *Deleting the code.interact line at the end and calling the "edit" method from the program itself (ie NOT from the interpreter) fixes the problem.*

In my troubleshooting, I have found that tkinter does not always play well when called from a python interpreter, which `code.interact` does.

**QUESTION**: Is there any way to preserve tkinter functionality from within a python interpreter? Is that *actually* my problem, or is it more to do with `code.interact`?

**UPDATE:** It seems that the issue relates to tkinter's mainloop running in tandem with code.interact's own loop. Two infinity loops competing with one another. Deleting either line seems to fix the issue. In this case, mainloop is not necessary for my GUI as it has no need to interactively update it's appearance.

Sample code below (then run `project_instance.edit()` from the python interpreter that follows)

```
import tkinter as tk
import code

class Project():
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.script = text

    def edit(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        S = tk.Scrollbar(root)
        T = tk.Text(root, height=60, width=60, undo=True, insertbackground="white", wrap=tk.WORD, font=("Courier", 30), background="black", foreground="grey")
        S.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        T.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
        S.config(command=T.yview)
        T.config(yscrollcommand=S.set)
        quote = self.script
        T.insert(tk.END, quote)

        def file_save():
            text2save = str(T.get(1.0, tk.END)).strip() # starts from `1.0`, not `0.0`
            with open("script_text.txt", "w") as s:
                s.write(text2save)
                uri = s.name
            root.destroy()
        b = tk.Button(root, height=5, width=10, font=("Courier", 44), text="Save", command=file_save, background="black", foreground="grey").pack()
        root.mainloop()


sample_text = "This is sample text."
project_instance = Project(sample_text)
code.interact(local=locals())
```

Comment: code is a standard python package. https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html put simply, after calling your python program from the terminal, it "drops you off" inside the python session. It is certainly part of the problem.

Comment: OK…then please provide a runnable [mre].

Comment: @martineau just added some sample code, thanks for your help

Comment: Calling `root.destroy()` in the `file_save()` function destroys the `root` and all its children. You should be able to exit the `mainloop()` more gracefully using `root.quit()`.

Comment: @martineau actually I have wondered what's the difference between `quit()` and `destroy()` methods, sometimes `quit()` does not work properly, so I use `destroy()`

Comment: @martineau quit() doesn't close the window either. I added a test print command right after both destroy and quit function and it prints - so the program is running past the quit function seemingly without issue. it prints after the destroy function too, but I also get a never ending pizza wheel. in both cases however, the window doesn't close.

Comment: Well, you can hide a window with `withdraw()`.

Comment: `quit()` just terminates `mainloop`. `destroy()` destroys the widget, and if you destroy the root window it also stops `mainloop`.

Comment: quit + withdraw seems to be a bandaid solution, as the interpreter remains usable, but the window still doesn't seem to close. just hides from view, running (frozen) in the background.

Comment: @BryanOakley the problem is 'destroy' freezes the program in this example. If the whole program / GUI were running in the terminal with "python3 app.py" for example, and thats it, then it would be fine. But calling a tkinter instance from the interpreter freezes upon destruction. not sure if its from ANY interpreter or just this one, generated by code.interact

Comment: I understand that. I was just clarifying the difference between `.destroy()` and `.quit()`.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: It seems that the issue relates to tkinter's mainloop running in tandem with code.interact's own loop. Two infinity loops competing with one another. Deleting either line seems to fix the issue. In this case, mainloop is not necessary for my GUI as it has no need to interactively update it's appearance.

Another fix is to destroy the root using the "after" method. `root.after(1, root.destroy())` which seems to be able to "escape" the competing loops as well.

I imagine threading would also work to isolate the loops from each other. More good info in this article:

[https://gordonlesti.com/use-tkinter-without-mainloop/#:~:text=The%20method%20mainloop%20has%20an,is%20waiting%20for%20some%20events](https://gordonlesti.com/use-tkinter-without-mainloop/#:%7E:text=The%20method%20mainloop%20has%20an,is%20waiting%20for%20some%20events).